# Directory path which does not physically exist on my device

Tags: file, python-3.x, path

I am learning Python programming language. Currently
I am experimenting  i-o files. I imported sys module and
 in sys.path list I saw two kinds of paths:

1. /data/data/org.qpython.qpy3....
2. /storage/sdcard0/qpthon...

The former path does not exist physically on my device
(Tablet), although I can create/read  files using this
path through python.
I want to know  about these paths.
What are they called?
What are they for? etc.

Answer (score 0):

The first path, **/data/data/org.qpython.qpy3**, this is where the actual QPython app is stored on your device. I don't believe you can access this path without having root access.

The second path, **/storage/sdcard0/qpthon**, this is where QPython saves files by default. It uses this location because it can be easily accessed with normal user privileges.

Comment: I have, through python, created files and read their contents.I can add here screen shots but there is no such facility on this website.

Comment: I have done this on the path /data/data/org.qpython.qpy3.